# impossible to give focus to an input

Tags: javascript, html

I need your help here, because I'm out of idea

I have the following HTML5 code

```
<form>
    <table class="main">
            <tr>
                    <td>Volume</td>
                    <td><input type="text" id="Q1" onblur="updateQ(Q1)" autofocus /></td>
                    <td>ml&nbsp;</td>
                    <td><input type="text" id="Q2" onblur="updateQ(Q2)" /></td>
                    <td>ml&nbsp;</td>
                    <td><input type="text" id="Qt" onblur="updateQ(Qt)" /></td>
                    <td>ml&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

and the following javascript function

```
function updateQ(ident) {
    var valeur = ident.value;
    var inputId = ident.id.toString();
    if (isNaN(valeur)) {
        ident.value = "";
        document.getElementById(inputId).focus();
    }
}
```

When the page is loaded, the first < input > get the focus.
I want to check if the user is entering only number, so "onblur" I call the function, which check the content.
If it's not a number, I remove the value and I try to give back the focus to the < input >

It doesn't work !

Impossible to give back the focus, the second input have it and it never goes back to the first one
I don't see any error in the Javascript console, and the rest of the script works nicely. 
Even giving the real id ("Q1") doesn't work ...

However, out of the function, giving the focus to another < input > works nicely

Any idea ?

Thanks in advance for your help

ericc

Comment: The parameter ident is just a string I guess. As far as I know you can't get .value and .id of a string. Edit: Use Matteo Tassinaris solution!

Comment: Can you create a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) or equivalent that recreates the problem, please? Also, which browser are you using?

Comment: Look fine: http://jsfiddle.net/cphnwmwm/

Comment: Don't see where's the problem http://jsbin.com/weqiduyezuhi/1/edit

Comment: Anyways, *clearing* inputs and stealing focus creates a really bad user experience. Consider instead applying some kind of error styling with an appropriate message and preventing the form from being submitted until things are fixed; HTML5 validation takes care of this for you, given support. If you feel that you must forcibly change the user’s focus, however, still don’t clear the textbox.

Comment: I'm using Firefox ... and I should have tried it in Chrome, my bad! I can't use the HTML5 validation as it's occur only on submit, and I want to build a dynamic tool without "submit" nor server-side processing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please see here http://jsbin.com/bapuyanuvula/1/

```
function updateQ(ident) {
  var valeur = ident.value;
  var inputId = ident.id.toString();
    if (isNaN(valeur)) {
      ident.value = "";
       setTimeout(function() {
        document.getElementById(inputId).focus();
    }, 0)

    }
}
```

The onblur event is happening while the user is leaving it. In some browsers this event can be canceled (i.e.: event.preventDefault()). So you can't focus it, because at this time it's still focused. So you either prevent the blur event or use a setTimeout as provided above...

Comment: Can you explain why that should change anything?

Comment: This works !! Perfect. So a Firefox issue :-( I was on this since 2 days . Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

This is browser related issue, Try this

```
function updateQ(ident) {
    var valeur = ident.value;
    var inputId = ident.id.toString();

    if (isNaN(valeur)) {
        ident.value = "";
        setTimeout(function(){                  
                    document.getElementById(inputId).focus();
                    },
            0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Its because you are passsing the wrong reference.
change this:

```
 onblur="updateQ(Q1)"
```

to this:

```
 onblur="updateQ(this)"
```

Comment: Better practice, maybe, but they’re equivalent.